# How could I resize my obstacles to be big when I enlarge my grid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, 3d

I'm trying to implement a 3D environment for a drone and I have distributed the obstacles randomly with random height. At every time running the position and the height of the obstacles will be different. My problem when I give 10*10 size to my grid it will work well and the size of obstacles will be acceptable, but when I make my grid for example 50*50, the obstacles will be too small and the image unclear. How could I solve the problem of the size of the obstacles? How could I enlarge them, but without making the cell interfere when I enlarge the grid?

Below 10*10 grid size

[image: 10*10 grid]
below 50*50 grid size
[image: 50*50 grid]
My try in python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import random
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import matplotlib.cm as cm

def display(elev_mp1, drone_height, risk_zone):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')

    ax.plot([0],[0],[0])
    ax.plot([0],[0],[1000])

    #x = np.linspace(0,len(elev_mp1),len(elev_mp1)+1)
    #y = np.linspace(0,len(elev_mp1),len(elev_mp1)+1)
    #X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
    #z = np.array([[0 for x in range(len(X[0]))]    for y in range(len(X))])

    num_bars = len(elev_mp1)*len(elev_mp1[0])
    x_pos = []
    y_pos = []

    for x in range(len(elev_mp1[0])):
        for y in range(len(elev_mp1)):
            x_pos.append(x)
            y_pos.append(y)
    z_pos = [0] * num_bars
    x_size = np.ones(num_bars)
    y_size = np.ones(num_bars)
    z_size = np.array(elev_mp1).flatten()

    color_values = []

    for x in z_size:
        if x >= drone_height:
            color_values.append([0,0,0,1])
        elif x in risk_zone:
            color_values.append([1,0,0,1])
        else:
            color_values.append([1,0,1,1])

    ax.bar3d(x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, x_size, y_size, z_size, color=color_values)

    #ax.plot_wireframe(X,Y,z)
    plt.show()

x = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)]
elev_mp1 = np.array([[0 for i in range(len(x[0]))]for j in range(len(x))])

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        if x[i][j] <= 0.96:
            elev_mp1[i][j] = 0
        else:
            elev_mp1[i][j] = 1
drone_height = 60

risk_zone = [x for x in range(40,60)]

for x in range(len(elev_mp1)):
    for y in range(len(elev_mp1[0])):
        if elev_mp1[x][y] == 1:
            elev_mp1[x][y] = random.randint(1,100)
        else:
            elev_mp1[x][y] = 0

display(elev_mp1, drone_height, risk_zone)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC your x- and y-sizes of the obstacles are defined by constant `1`, i.e. by `np.ones(num_bars)`.

I assume you set your grid size hardcoded by the use of `range(10)`, but when you want to have your obstacles scaled by e.g. a factor 5 in x and y, you can simply add this factor to the definition lines of the size arrays:

```
a = 5    # or however you want to create/control this factor in your program

x_size = a * np.ones(num_bars)
y_size = a * np.ones(num_bars)
```

Perhaps you should think about e.g. setting the gridsize as a variable Parameter and the obstacle size as a fraction of it, so it scales automatically as soon as you change your gridsize.

(btw: you can leave a second size variable and use e.g. `size = a * np.ones(num_bars)` for both directions if you have squared obstacles anyway...)

Comment: I set my grid size here x = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)] in this line.

Comment: What do you mean dear by (you can leave a second size variable and use e.g. size = a * np.ones(num_bars) for both directions if you have squared obstacles anyway). How could I do it?

Comment: Exactly, by hardcoding `10` into this line. Set a Parameter `grid_size = 10` at the beginning of your script, replace the `10`s by it accordingly and define your obstacle sizes e.g. by `x_size = .1*grid_size * np.ones(num_bars)`.

Comment: With _you can leave a second size variable ..._ I meant: if your obstacles have the same size in x as they have in y - you  _could_ simply define one single size variable for both like e.g. `width = .1*grid_size * np.ones(num_bars)`. And this is then used in your barplot command for both x and y kwargs: `ax.bar3d(x_pos, y_pos, z_pos, width, width, z_size, color=color_values)`

Comment: Great idea, but this will not contradict with my grid size in the loop? x = [[random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10)]for j in range(10)]

Comment: I don't understand - do you change your gridsize from 10 to 50 by simply typing 50 into this `x = ...` line instead of 10? Then - for a first test - do it again and write `5 * np.ones(num_bars)` in your x_size definition.

Comment: The full-size cell for the obstacle is 1x1, if we change it then it will cover the neighboring area. I resized the obstacle to 5x5, and only gave 4 obstacles in the grid, it closed all grid areas.

Comment: Ok sorry, then completely do not understand your problem. From my point of view, you want to create a larger grid (50x50 instead of 10x10), one cell has to be fix 1x1 but you wonder that 1x1 is smaller against 50x50 than against 10x10...?

Comment: Could you explain then, what you mean? If you have 10 cells plotted onto 10cm, one cell is 1cm. If you plot 50 cells onto the same line of 10cm length, one cell is 2mm. So what do you expect?

Comment: I got your point dear now. Maybe I'm wrong, but how could we enlarge them without interfering?

Comment: If your cell size is 1 and your obstacle size is 1 - there's exactly 0 space left for making the obstacle bigger without interfering with neighbour cells.

Comment: I got your point. I'll try to fix it. Thank you so much dear for your replies.

Comment: If you perhaps simply have this diffuse feeling, that obstacles seem to be so unwanted smaller when increasing grid size... - perhaps you simply choose a bigger figure size? Fast way: Click on maximize button. Other, more controllable way: `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))`

Comment: Thank you so much dear for your help.